# How do you merge two pandas dataframes with the same attributes and overwrite the rows that are identical?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets that I would like to merge. A simplified version is:

```
DF1
----
name age country
joe  25  uk
jim  24  usa
jill 46  spain

DF2
---
name age country
joe  25  uk
jim  24  usa
sam  27  france
```

I would like to merge the two datasets to produce

```
DF3
---
name age country
joe  25  uk
jim  24  usa
sam  27  france
jill 46  spain
```

Can anybody suggest how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it this particular case is to append df2 to df1 and then drop duplicates

```py
df3 = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop= True)
```

Comment: @LogiGunaratnam Great ! Consider  validating / accepting the answer plz - Thanks

Comment: I've accepted this one as the answer thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

via outer merge:

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer')
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   name  age country
0   joe   25      uk
1   jim   24     usa
2  jill   46   spain
3   sam   27  france
```

NOTE: sort by age column if requried:

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer').sort_values('age')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help the two datasets Im using although they have the same columns  I get a float64 error when i try this method.